# Difference between GetObject("", progId) and GetObject(, progId)

Tags: c#, com, vbscript

I'm trying to build an out-of-process COM server in C#. I've found this example from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977996

I've build it and tested with a little VBScript:

```
Set app = GetObject("", "CSExeCOMServer.CSSimpleObject")
WScript.Echo(app.HelloWorld())
```

It works, but not when I do like this (skip the first argument of GetObject):

```
Set app = GetObject(, "CSExeCOMServer.CSSimpleObject")
WScript.Echo(app.HelloWorld())
```

I don't understand the difference between this two calls. I need the second form, because I want to make my calls from an environnement where only the second way is available.

What can I change to the server in order to make this works?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as often, I've found the solution by myself. In fact:

```
GetObject("", "CSExeCOMServer.CSSimpleObject")
```

is the same thing as:

```
CreateObject("CSExeCOMServer.CSSimpleObject")
```

If you were looking for a bad designed API, I've found one (but I don't know the whole story, may be someone here can explain me why it is like this).

The problem in my case is that the Microsoft sample doesn't register an object in the ROT (Running Object Table). So the GetObject call can not find an active object. I've resolved this by creating an instance of my class after adding this method to the constructor:

```
public void AddToROT()
{
    IRunningObjectTable rot = null;
    IMoniker moniker = null;
    try
    {
        // Get the ROT
        rot = GetRunningObjectTable(0);

        // Create a moniker for the graph
        moniker = CreateItemMoniker("!", "{" + CLASS_ID  + "}");

        // Registers the graph in the running object table
        cookie = rot.Register(ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE, this, moniker);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (null != moniker) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(moniker);
        if (null != rot) Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(rot);
    }
}
```